# Calculate cell value based on formula and values in other cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in a HTML file, and I want to calculate one cell's value based on other cells' values and a cell value as a formula. Take a look at this picture:

[image: my table calculate]

In my table, I have 1900 ratios and three factors in three columns. How I can calculate the result column values based on their respective formula column value?

**Note:** I use only `*`, `/`, `+`, and `-` in my formulas. Also, the table has an ID (`ratiotable`), but the `<tr>` and `<td>` don't have any ID or class names assigned to them.

If you know another webpage that did something like this, please let me see this.

Thank you very much.

**Edit:** The HTML code is like this. Note, I snipped a number of the rows. The actual number of rows is 1900:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Ratio Name</th>
        <th>Factor1</th>
        <th>Factor2</th>
        <th>Factor3</th>
        <th>Formula</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Factor1/Factor2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Factor1/Factor2*Factor3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>(Factor1+Factor2)/Factor3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you place the actual html you are using for it

Comment: @rahul I edited the question just now

Comment: that's gud now can you please tell me that your formula will be in this terms only Factor1 Factor2...

Comment: @rahul. Yes my formulas have only 3 factors

Comment: you can see Chris Francis answer i think this will give you a start

Comment: I don't usually believe in writing out such a 'complete' solution on SO, but I was too intrigued by this not to try it! `/geekout`

Comment: +1 for your answer  Chris Francis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a really interesting challenge. I've put together a little [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/tTfmg/6/) that does what you describe. It essentially replaces the string parts of the formula with their value counterparts, then evals the result. Hopefully this helps!

**My Markup**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ratio Name</th>
            <th>Factor1</th>
            <th>Factor2</th>
            <th>Factor3</th>
            <th>Formula</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Factor1/Factor2</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Factor1/Factor2*Factor3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>(Factor1+Factor2)/Factor3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

​
**My JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            f1 = $this.find('td').eq(1).text() || 0,
            f2 = $this.find('td').eq(2).text() || 0,
            f3 = $this.find('td').eq(3).text() || 0,
            formula = $this.find('td').eq(4).text(),
            resultTd = $this.find('td').last();

       formula = formula.replace('Factor1',f1)
                        .replace('Factor2',f2)
                        .replace('Factor3',f3);

        resultTd.text(eval(formula));
    });
});​
```

Comment: Great answer! I took the liberty of also copying your code to the answer itself for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 3):

loop through all rows and use javascript eval() function

```
function cellValue(x,y){
    return $('#ratiotable').find('tr:eq('+(y+1)+')>td:eq('+(x+1)+')').text();    
}

function setCellValue(x,y,s){
    $('#ratiotable').find('tr:eq('+(y+1)+')>td:eq('+(x+1)+')').text(s);    
}

$(function(){
    $.each($('#ratiotable tr'),function(i,tr){
        var Factor1 = parseInt(cellValue(0,i));
        var Factor2 = parseInt(cellValue(1,i));
        var Factor3 = parseInt(cellValue(2,i));
        var Formula = $.trim(cellValue(3,i));
        var Result = eval(Formula);
        setCellValue(4,i,Result);
    });    
});
```

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/L6fRj/1/)

Comment: Thanks but the formula column determine how i should calculate the results and also unfortunately the number of table's rows are 1900.

Comment: then loops through each row, get the cells values and show the result !